# Disable converting NSString

Tags: objective-c, swift

In my objectivec code I have:

```
   @property (nonatomic, nullable) NSString* position;
```

in swift it is converted to a String type. Can I disable that conversion? I would like to use NSString type in swift also

at the moment my swift code looks like this:

```
 (a.position as NSString?)?.intValue
```

Comment: what type of a variable or property do you want to declare?

Comment: Why don't you do `Int(a.position)` instead? Swift & Objective-C have a lot in common (beside the Cocoa(Touch) frameworks), but they have some different logic too. Avoid doing Swift in Objective-C, or Objective-C in Swift.

Comment: "I don't use Int(a.position) because I think it can crash, depending on the string" Any example for that crash?

Comment: @Larme Sorry for the confusion, it really does not crash. The crash I remember was when instead of NSString the object was NSNumber and objc did not crash (because intValue is available), but swift did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable that conversation. But you can use `Int(a.position ?? "")` to convert `String` to `Int`. It's safe because this initializer is optional.

Comment: Int("3.2") returns nil, but I want it to be 3 - similar to intValue. Any suggestion?

Comment: If `position` is decimal number, than you can convert it to `Double` and after that - to `Int`: `Int(Double(a.position))`

Comment: @IlyaKharabet - Except that the largest `Int` value requires 19 decimal digits and `Double` only has a precision of 15 - 17 decimal digits.

Comment: @KamenDobrev - check for a decimal point and only convert the slice of the string before the point to an integer. Look at `String` methods to find and slice at the point. Don't use floating point math and then truncate to integer. You can bundle up your code as an extension on `Int`, so you could write, say, `Int(objcIntValue: someString)`.